# Is X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM really deprecated?

Tags: firefox, iframe, http-headers

I am not sure about the exact status of this HTTP header. Some source - for instance [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) or [Caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=allow-from) - clearly indicate that this header has been removed since the version 70 of Firefox, and has been replaced by `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors`.

Despite of that, I can see that `X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM myServerURI` is still working : using Firefox 75, I clearly see that setting this header or not server side has still an impact on an iFrame : the inner content is allowed or is blocked when the header is present or not.

Examining the server's response headers using Firefox F12 / Web developer tools, Network, Headers clearly shows the presence of this header and the impact on the result. In this situation, there is also a `Content-Security-Policy` header present, but without the `frame-ancestors` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Something must be wrong with your test.

When I try using it in Firefox 75, I get an error in the console:

> Invalid X-Frame-Options: “ALLOW-FROM `http://www.example.com/`” header from “`http://localhost:7007/`” loaded into “`http://localhost:8080/`”.

… and the content is displayed in the frame even though the iframe is hosted on `http://localhost:8080/` and not `http://www.example.com/`

Comment: I'm glad you've done the test. I've just done it again and had a look into the browser console, no message. Tested on Firefox 75 on Linux but also on Chrome 81 on Windows.
The context is the inclusion of a webmail tool called Rainloop. They have an option `x_frame_options_header` and the inclusion within my website works fine when I set it to `ALLOW-FROM https://myWebSite` and does not work when I leave this option empty. Using FFox / F12 clearly shows that the `X-Frame-Options` is set to this `x_frame_options_header` option's content.

Answer (score 0):

**ALLOW-FROM** value for **X-Frame-Options** header is obsolete now and not supported by new browsers.
Refer this link for valid possible values : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options